# What does it mean to have a 'saucy facial expression'?

Tags: meaning, expressions, meaning-in-context

What does it mean to have a 'saucy facial expression'?

I came upon a comment saying that and I have no idea what it means.

Comment: It means a humorous expression.

Comment: It means cheeky or sexually provocative in some contexts.

Comment: Would meanings 2 to 4 of the [Wiktionary entry for saucy](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/saucy) make sense in the context of the comment?

Comment: I'd say 3 and 4 are the closest matches, probably 4.

Comment: Is this not enough or what? http://www.thefreedictionary.com/saucy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends if you are in Britain or America.

In the great Puritan United States it means simply 'expressing a bold, spirited, or lively manner'.

In Britain it can have a number of meanings, the most likely being 'sexually suggestive in a light-hearted and humorous way'.  But it can also mean simply 'cheeky and impertinent' and have nothing to do with sex at all. It depends on context.

If a barmaid, when taking your order for turkey says 'are you a breast man, or a leg man', that is a 'saucy remark' in the first sense. People also talk about 'saucy postcards' which you buy at the seaside, featuring cartoons of red-faced men and overweight or underweight, scantily clad women,   with *double-entendre* captions. They also are 'saucy' in the sexual sense.

If someone writes you a sarcastic letter of complaint, let's say about some business dealings, which you consider unreasonable, you might refer to it as a 'saucy letter'. That is the second meaning.

Remember that in Britain we pronounce the word 'SORSEY'. Americans say something that sounds like 'SASSY'.

- Meanings taken from Oxford Dictionary of English (not OED)

Comment: You're right of course, but have you actually heard anyone refer to sauce meaning cheek in the last 30 years? It seems incredibly dated usage to me.

Comment: @TheMathemagician It is perhaps less often used than it used to be, but I will certainly have heard it used in the last 30 years, particularly among business people deriding some offer that has been made to them. But I agree that it probably people of my age and above who will be most inclined to use it.

Comment: Good answer, although I'd say that Americans pronounce it SOSSY – SASSY is a related but different word.